# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher

Tags: flutter

iam working with a musicplayer app and it runs fine with chrome but when i tried to run on emulator iam getting this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

\* What went wrong:

The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.

The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:

project ':audioplayers' -\> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32

\* Try:

\\\> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

\\\> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

\\\> Run with --scan to get full insights.

BUILD FAILED in 22s

Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the latest version of  dependecy audioplayers as per the error thats old :  https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

Comment: thanks:) it worked there is a noise issue when it start to play